# 1 value to have 2 keys array

Tags: php

I am making search engine on latin and cyrilic that eather way writing it it will show results in both lanugages.Everything works well with my script but the problem is with "S", "C" when people write them they have 2 meaning letters, latin "S" is equal to cyrilic "С" and "Ш" or latin "C" to "Ц" and "Ч". So can anybody help me with this.Thanks!

My script:

```
$cyrToLat = array(
                        "а"=>"a","б"=>"b","в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d","ѓ"=>"gj","е"=>"e","ж"=>"zh","з"=>"z","ѕ"=>"s",
                        "и"=>"i","ј"=>"j","к"=>"k","л"=>"l","љ"=>"lj","м"=>"m","н"=>"n","њ"=>"nj","о"=>"o","п"=>"p",
                        "р"=>"r","с"=>"s","т"=>"t","ќ"=>"kj","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h","ц"=>"c","џ"=>"dz","ч"=>"ch",
                        "ш"=>"sh","А"=>"A","Б"=>"B","В"=>"V","Г"=>"G","Д"=>"D","Ѓ"=>"GJ","Е"=>"E","Ж"=>"ZH","З"=>"Z",
                        "Ѕ"=>"S","И"=>"I","Ј"=>"J","К"=>"K","Л"=>"L","Љ"=>"LJ","М"=>"M","Н"=>"N","Њ"=>"NJ","О"=>"O",
                        "П"=>"P","Р"=>"R","С"=>"S","Т"=>"T","Ќ"=>"KJ","У"=>"U","Ф"=>"F","Х"=>"H","Ц"=>"C","Џ"=>"DZ",
                        "Ч"=>"CH","Ш"=>"SH","Ѓ"=>"Gj","Ж"=>"Zh","Љ"=>"Lj","Њ"=>"Nj","Ќ"=>"Kj","Џ"=>"Dz","Ч"=>"Ch",
                        "Ч"=>"C","Ш"=>"S"
);

$latToCyr = array(
                        "a"=>"а","b"=>"б","v"=>"в","g"=>"г","d"=>"д","gj"=>"ѓ","e"=>"е","zh"=>"ж","z"=>"з","s"=>"ѕ",
                        "i"=>"и","j"=>"ј","k"=>"к","l"=>"л","lj"=>"љ","m"=>"м","n"=>"н","nj"=>"њ","o"=>"о","p"=>"п",
                        "r"=>"р","s"=>"с","t"=>"т","kj"=>"ќ","u"=>"у","f"=>"ф","h"=>"х","c"=>"ц","dz"=>"џ","ch"=>"ч",
                        "sh"=>"ш","A"=>"А","B"=>"Б","V"=>"В","G"=>"Г","D"=>"Д","GJ"=>"Ѓ","E"=>"Е","ZH"=>"Ж","Z"=>"З",
                        "S"=>"Ѕ","I"=>"И","J"=>"Ј","K"=>"К","L"=>"Л","LJ"=>"Љ","M"=>"М","N"=>"Н","NJ"=>"Њ","O"=>"О",
                        "P"=>"П","R"=>"Р","S"=>"С","T"=>"Т","KJ"=>"Ќ","U"=>"У","F"=>"Ф","H"=>"Х","C"=>"Ц","DZ"=>"Џ",
                        "CH"=>"Ч","SH"=>"Ш","Gj"=>"Ѓ","Zh"=>"Ж","Lj"=>"Љ","Nj"=>"Њ","Kj"=>"Ќ","Dz"=>"Џ","Ch"=>"Ч",
                        "C"=>"Ч","S"=>"Ш"
                    );  
    }

$word = strip_tags(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search'])));
$keyword_lat = strtr($word,$cyrToLat);
$keyword_cyr = strtr($word,$latToCyr);
```

---

Ok here is working code . I found solution for my problem thanks to oleksii.svarychevskyi

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $cyrToLat = array(
                    "а"=>"a","б"=>"b","в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d","ѓ"=>"gj","е"=>"e","ж"=>"zh","з"=>"z","ѕ"=>"s",
                    "и"=>"i","ј"=>"j","к"=>"k","л"=>"l","љ"=>"lj","м"=>"m","н"=>"n","њ"=>"nj","о"=>"o","п"=>"p",
                    "р"=>"r","с"=>"s","т"=>"t","ќ"=>"kj","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h","ц"=>"c","џ"=>"dz","ч"=>"ch",
                    "ш"=>"sh","А"=>"A","Б"=>"B","В"=>"V","Г"=>"G","Д"=>"D","Ѓ"=>"GJ","Е"=>"E","Ж"=>"ZH","З"=>"Z",
                    "Ѕ"=>"S","И"=>"I","Ј"=>"J","К"=>"K","Л"=>"L","Љ"=>"LJ","М"=>"M","Н"=>"N","Њ"=>"NJ","О"=>"O",
                    "П"=>"P","Р"=>"R","С"=>"S","Т"=>"T","Ќ"=>"KJ","У"=>"U","Ф"=>"F","Х"=>"H","Ц"=>"C","Џ"=>"DZ",
                    "Ч"=>"CH","Ш"=>"SH","Ѓ"=>"Gj","Ж"=>"Zh","Љ"=>"Lj","Њ"=>"Nj","Ќ"=>"Kj","Џ"=>"Dz","Ч"=>"Ch",
                    "Ч"=>"C","Ш"=>"S"
                );
    $cyrToLatArr = array("ч"=>"c");
    $latToCyr = array(
                    "a"=>"а","b"=>"б","v"=>"в","g"=>"г","d"=>"д","gj"=>"ѓ","e"=>"е","zh"=>"ж","z"=>"з","s"=>"ѕ",
                    "i"=>"и","j"=>"ј","k"=>"к","l"=>"л","lj"=>"љ","m"=>"м","n"=>"н","nj"=>"њ","o"=>"о","p"=>"п",
                    "r"=>"р","s"=>"с","t"=>"т","kj"=>"ќ","u"=>"у","f"=>"ф","h"=>"х","c"=>"ц","dz"=>"џ","ch"=>"ч",
                    "sh"=>"ш","A"=>"А","B"=>"Б","V"=>"В","G"=>"Г","D"=>"Д","GJ"=>"Ѓ","E"=>"Е","ZH"=>"Ж","Z"=>"З",
                    "S"=>"Ѕ","I"=>"И","J"=>"Ј","K"=>"К","L"=>"Л","LJ"=>"Љ","M"=>"М","N"=>"Н","NJ"=>"Њ","O"=>"О",
                    "P"=>"П","R"=>"Р","S"=>"С","T"=>"Т","KJ"=>"Ќ","U"=>"У","F"=>"Ф","H"=>"Х","C"=>"Ц","DZ"=>"Џ",
                    "CH"=>"Ч","SH"=>"Ш","Gj"=>"Ѓ","Zh"=>"Ж","Lj"=>"Љ","Nj"=>"Њ","Kj"=>"Ќ","Dz"=>"Џ","Ch"=>"Ч",
                    "C"=>"Ч","S"=>"Ш",
                );  
    $latToCyrArr = array("c"=>"ч");
    $word = strip_tags(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search'])));

    $m_lat = array_merge($latToCyr, $latToCyrArr,$cyrToLatArr);
    $keyword_lat = strtr($word,$m_lat);

    $keyword_cyr = strtr($word,$cyrToLat);
```

Comment: I've no idea what your problem really is. If someone uses S or C, you need to get the result for both curilic letters back.

Comment: Well you know what the correct spelling is. I've no idea and neither does a php script, until you tell it the "rules".

Comment: Just want that value "C" to have both keys "Ч" and "Ц" something like array("c"=>"ч","ц")

Comment: You can do that. Either as an array (you can have an array in an array, that would be 'c' => array("ч","ц") ) or you use if ($letter == 'c') { /* handle both values */ }

Comment: `array("c"=> array("ч","ц"))` but in this case strtr function will not work.

Comment: already try that it gave me  error message  "Array to string conversion in "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have factored your code.
$latToCyrArr now contains arrays with possible translation. But all symbols that have several values you need to move to separate arrays. As a result you will get the array of possible translations.

```
$latToCyrABase = array(
"a"=>"а","b"=>"б","v"=>"в","g"=>"г","d"=>"д","gj"=>"ѓ","e"=>"е","zh"=>"ж","z"=>"з","s"=>"ѕ",
"i"=>"и","j"=>"ј","k"=>"к","l"=>"л","lj"=>"љ","m"=>"м","n"=>"н","nj"=>"њ","o"=>"о","p"=>"п",
"r"=>"р","s"=>"с","t"=>"т","kj"=>"ќ","u"=>"у","f"=>"ф","h"=>"х","c"=>"ц","dz"=>"џ","ch"=>"ч",
"sh"=>"ш","A"=>"А","B"=>"Б","V"=>"В","G"=>"Г","D"=>"Д","GJ"=>"Ѓ","E"=>"Е","ZH"=>"Ж","Z"=>"З",
"S"=>"Ѕ","I"=>"И","J"=>"Ј","K"=>"К","L"=>"Л","LJ"=>"Љ","M"=>"М","N"=>"Н","NJ"=>"Њ","O"=>"О",
"P"=>"П","R"=>"Р","S"=>"С","T"=>"Т","KJ"=>"Ќ","U"=>"У","F"=>"Ф","H"=>"Х","C"=>"Ц","DZ"=>"Џ",
"CH"=>"Ч","SH"=>"Ш","Gj"=>"Ѓ","Zh"=>"Ж","Lj"=>"Љ","Nj"=>"Њ","Kj"=>"Ќ","Dz"=>"Џ","Ch"=>"Ч"
);
$latToCyrArr = array(
    array("C"=>"Ч", "c"=>"ч"),
    array("S"=>"Ш")
);


$word = 'covek';
$keyword_lat_arr = array();
foreach ($latToCyrArr as $latToCyr) {
    $keyword_lat = strtr($word, array_merge($latToCyrABase, $latToCyr));
    if (!in_array($keyword_lat, $keyword_lat_arr)) {
        $keyword_lat_arr[] = $keyword_lat;
    }
}
print_r($keyword_lat_arr);
```

### Update

for sql query

```
$like = array();
//for every variable which is array do this
foreach ($keyword_lat as $value) {
$like[] = "jtitle LIKE '%".$value%."'";
}
foreach ($keyword_cyr as $value) {
$like[] = "jtitle LIKE '%".$value%."'";
}
$like[] = "jtitle LIKE '".%$word%."'";
$like = implode(' OR ', $like);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE $like ORDER BY adverts.id DESC";
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: when i write covek it finds "covek" and "човек" that's good but it didnt recognize letter "c" as "ц" it needs latin "c" to recognize "ч" and "ц" word

Comment: So just modify first array to contain "c"=>"ц" and second array to contain "c"=>"ч".

Comment: Code was updated try it now.

Comment: OK nice code :) what about cyr to lat when I change your code same for cyr to lat we are back as previous got to results covek and цовек but not човек and i need all 3. I think something else is wrong mb with query inpu so i update the code that i posted mb there is problem becouse your code is correct and good.

Comment: So do you need more help?

Comment: yes can you look my query i update the code mb something is wrong with the query your code si good and correct but still problem is there I am getting the array Array ( [0] => ч [1] => ц )  but search doesnt recognize it recognize one of them thats why i think something is wrong mb in query

Comment: My search engine takes last array ...

Comment: Thank you man I've update the code ... I found the solution thanks to you :)

Comment: If my answer helped you can you vote and accept it?

Comment: Cant vote but I would gladly man I have low reputation sry :( many thanks again for taking time too look the code :)